# specify a date for an event

Tags: android

for example i want to start  the event on monday at 13:30 and finish it at 15:30 , how can i do it ?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
event.put("calendar_id",1);
event.put("title", "dd");
event.put("description","dd");
event.put("eventLocation", calc.getEventLocation());
event.put("dtstart",???);
event.put("rrule", "FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;BYDAY=WE");
event.put("allDay", 1);   // 0 for false, 1 for true
event.put("eventStatus", 1);
event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
event.put("duration","P3600S");
getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `java.util.Date` object, set the desired date and time. If you DB needs a String then convert date to string, if long then date to long. And provide appropriate value to `"dtstart"`

Along with stStart, you also need to have dtEnd. Here the date wil lremain same but the time will change.

Do the above for both objects - ststart & dtend.

If you don't have to add another field to your DB, then you will have to pass a customized String. Like : "Feb-6-2012|13:30|15:30" or so. Here I have seperated Date, Start Time & end Time with a "|" (pipe) char. When you retrieve the value from DB, you got to parse accordingly and can make 2 instances of Date for start and end time.

Hope this helps.